# Elementary Problems with Strings and Integers in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to learn Python with the help of Project Euler.

I'm having a bit of trouble with this piece of code (For Problem 2) and what exactly a 'Non type' is. I was wondering if anyone could help point me in the right direction!

```
from math import sqrt
x= 0 

def f(n):
    return ((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5))

def SubFib(startNumber, endNumber):
    n = 0
    cur = f(n)
        while cur <= endNumber:
        if startNumber <= cur:
        print (cur)
        n += 1
        cur = f(n)


        for i in range(SubFib(1,4000000)):
        if i % 2 ==0:
        x = i+ x
```

Thank-You in Advance!

Comment: Wekcome to Stack overflow! Please check the indentation of your code - as it stands it doesn't look like it would work... You should also post the exact error you see (usually with traceback) and what you expected (don't assume that people will definitely work it out - they might in this case, but not generally).  Make sure you've read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Good luck!

Comment: Once you've fixed the `NoneType` next issue is `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` as a result of `SubFib(1,4000000)`. Does it always need to be this high a value?

Answer (score 2):

A `NoneType` error is what happens when something has the value `None` and you try to do something with it. In this case, your `SubFib` function never returns anything, so when you call it and pass its result to `range()`, it tries to run `range(None)`.

Perhaps you want `SubFib` to have a `return n` at the end?